# What is the way to use variable expression in thymeleaf 2.5.6 version

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

> I just create simple template by the help of thmeleaf, When I try to
> access the variable from controller class by the help of variable
> Expression , But I get Issue on variable expression ,In the time of
> variable expression access . Showing below type of error

```
cannot Resolve variable name
```

> My variable name is today which  I define in my controller class
> Homecontroller.kt

```
package com.nilmani.thymeleafdemo.controller

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.thymeleaf.ITemplateEngine
import org.thymeleaf.context.WebContext
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import javax.servlet.ServletContext
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

@RestController
class HomeController : IGTVGController() {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun process(request:HttpServletRequest,response: HttpServletResponse,
               servletContext: ServletContext,templateEngine: ITemplateEngine){
        val dateForm:SimpleDateFormat= SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy")
        val calendar:Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val ctx : WebContext = WebContext(request,response,servletContext,request.locale)
        ctx.setVariable("today",dateForm.format(calendar.time))
        templateEngine.process("home",ctx,response.writer)

    }
}
```

> home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
       <title>Welcome TO our WebPage</title>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
               href="../../css/gtvg.css" th:href="@{/css/gtvg.css}" />
   </head>

 <body>
 <p th:utext="#{home.welcome}">Welcome to our website</p>
 <p>Today is: <span th:text= "${today}"></span></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

> error shows at this point below point

```
 th:text= "${today}"
```

> What is the reason for not support of variable expression . I already
> added thymeleaf gradle depedency in my project.But the variable
> expression not working

Comment: Can you please include actual error log message in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Kotlin, so I hope you can convert my Java answer to it.

1. I see you use `@RestController`, but if you are using Thymeleaf, use `@Controller`
2. You can have Spring Boot inject the `Model` class and add your attributes there
3. The easiest is to return a String value that represents the name of the Thymeleaf template.

Using all that, you get something like this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

  public String process(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("today", ...);
    return "home"; //this refers to home.html like this
  }

}
```

PS: You should not use `Calendar` anymore, see https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro for more info on the "new" date/time API introduced in Java 8.

Comment: It does not matter in my controller, I want to know when I use variable expression in my html page by the help of thymeleaf , I am not able to pass variable inside variable expression . what is the reason ? Every project I get issue at the time of variable expression implementation in thymeleaf

Comment: It seems the user wants to had control over the generated html by templateEngine rather than returning the html in the response.

Comment: I cannot understand,  thymeleaf is not supported in jar file , But Supports in war file  what is the reason, I solve above issue , convert my application  to war  it works fine , But in jar thymeleaf not support many thymeleaf contents